# How do I apply character A's pose to character B?

Tags: pose-mode

I have 2 characters and made a pose for one of them. Now I want the other character to have the same pose, what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Does each character have the same rig?

Comment: Yes. I tried just copying and pasting all locations and rotations for each part, but it took pretty long and didn't really work in some places.

Comment: Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/copy-animation-from-rig-to-rig  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39281/how-to-copy-data-from-one-armature-to-another-pose-mode