# RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'thigh.L': Heel bone not found. Incorrect armature for type 'leg'

Tags: rigging

[image]

I am encountering the following error when attempting to generate my rigify rig

> RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'thigh.L': Heel bone not found. Incorrect armature for type 'leg'

Here is a very similar discussion: [Adding a knee bone for better definition to Rigify metarig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186070/adding-a-knee-bone-for-better-definition-to-rigify-metarig)

However, the issue with that discussion is that it is not specific to the problem, and hence does not provide a clear solution.

Can someone explain in simple terms why this issue is occuring and what needs to be done to fix it so I can generate my rig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental reason why I was encountering this issue was that I had modified the rigify skeleton around the feet. What had happened was that I had added an extra bone in the foot to allow for better control, but because of this new bone, RIGIFY was not able to generate a rig for me.

`Image: Extra bone`
[image]
[image]

Another issue on top of this was the fact that `Heel bone` became disconnected and therefore was `not found.` By remaking the connection, the error resolved.

Comment: Similar discussion on a different website: https://blenderartists.org/t/accidentally-deleted-a-rigify-bone-now-i-cant-generate-the-rig-how-do-i-fix-this/1250297/5