# Rigify leg with 5 bone chain

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I have a rigify armature I'm setting up, and the leg bone has 5 bones, despite the fact that rigify only allows at most 4 bones in a leg bone chain. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: This post may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186070/adding-a-knee-bone-for-better-definition-to-rigify-metarig?rq=1