# Why is the generate rig button greyed out?

Tags: armature, rigify, append

I have appended a Rigify metarig from the *Armature* category from an older blend file via the *File > Append...* main menu. In the older project, the metarig's *(Re-)Generate Rig* button is not grayed out and works. But for the appended metarig, the button is greyed out and you can't (re-)create the animation rig.

What is the reason for this? How to append it correctly?

[image: screeenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Do not append metarigs from the *Armature* category. Instead, append them from the *Object* category.

[image: screenshot]