# How i can add rigify side panel?

Tags: rigify, panel

[image: this panel]In blender 3.6 rigify side panel (n) which contain ik is missing and also there is no script found to run..

Comment: It's there on a quick model that I rigged. What script are you talking about? - I presume you are in pose mode with one of the rigify control bones selected?

Comment: You're going to have to give us some context, to make this answerable.. perhaps illustrate a _difference_ between what you expect, from an earlier version, and what you're getting. in 3.6.

Comment: i added photo for the panel i don't find .... even when i try to find abi_ui.py and rig_ui.py

Comment: Thank you for the picture, but sorry there is still too little context. We still don't know what you have done. Have you used Rigify and created the rig yourself or have you downloaded a rigged model? The script (rig_ui.py) which creates the custom panel is created and executed by the Rigify add-on when you press the 'Generate Rig' button. Have you done this?

Comment: Thank you so much for you .... I tried to generate rig and its work with me ....but i can't do same with ready characters ???

Comment: The script should be included for the ready-rigged character model in the blend file. Each Rigify animation rig has an ID, that is used in the script (see *Object Data Properties tab ("running man" icon) > Custom Properties > rig_id* of the "rig" object. At worst and if it's a Rigify rig, you can [extract the meta-rig from the animation rig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/234123/107598), and then re-generate the rig and the script. Use *Parent To > With Empty Groups* to keep the existing weights when you re-bind the mesh.