# Merge a standard armature into a rigify armature with bone merging

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, rigify

I have two armatures. One is a character model that has a rigify armature on it. The other is a jacket that has standard bones.

The jacket's spine bone's names are different from the character's ORG bone names, but nearly have the same location, rotation and scale.

The character armature contains extra bones that aren't rigify.

For reference, here are the jacket's bones
[image]

And the character's ORG bones
[image]

What I want, is to merge the jacket's armature into the character's, remove any bones from the jacket's armature that have a similar counterpart in the charater's armature, and keep any extra bones from the jacket. Finally, the jacket should be influenced by the rigify armature.

How should I do that?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.  Also adding images pointing to what you are referring to would also help.

Comment: I cna't really put my own model as it's a bit NSFW, and I'm not sure how to make an example model of a rigify.
Did add pictures tho

Comment: by *"I have two armatures."* you mean you have 2 rigged models, one jacket and one character, so two 2 armatures and two meshes, and you want to merge them now so you have one Rigify armature that controls both meshes? -- You could extract the meta rig from the Rigify animation rig  (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/234123/107598), then add the custom bones for the jacket there, assign the rig types, and re-generate the animation rig. Then you need to rename the vertex groups that contain the weights for the jacket or weight paint it.