# Various rigify errors in wolf rig spine

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

This is my first time using Blender. I've tried to add a wolf rig, which worked out fine but the spine was twisted. I selected the spine bones and pressed <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd> and recalculated roll to active bone.

That solved the problem, however, now I get errors when recalculating the rig. I've already looked up ways to fix those errors but whenever I try to fix one error I just end up with a new error. The errors I've had are:

`RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.005': Input to rig type must be a chain of at most 3 bones. Incorrect armature for type 'limb_rigs'`

`RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.003': Cannot connect to non-chain parent rig. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'`

`RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.003': Cannot connect chain - bone position is disjoint. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'`

And currently I'm at this error:

`RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.004': Input to rig type must be a chain of 3 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'`

I really don't know how to fix it.

[FOX.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cr2bxcc440xg4n/FOX.blend?dl=0)

Comment: The errors you are getting are the sort that imply that you may have accidentally removed bones from the metarig before you tried to generate the rig; possibly while you were editing the rig to match your fox.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: rigged fox]

If you have that many errors I would start over with a fresh meta rig. You can use the script from this question ([Rigify->Generate Rig doesn't create all rig layers in the properties ui](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/108975/107598)) to copy the layout of the bones so that your work is not lost.

**Besides the mentioned errors there are a few issues that you should solve first**.

- the *FOX* mesh has 25 duplicated vertices. Merge them in *Edit* mode with <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*
- the meta-rig is a child of the generated rig. This is not necessary. Select it and clear its parent (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- everything is rotated by 90° around the Z-axis. This is bad because when you select menu *View > Viewpoint > Front* (<kbd>Numpad_1</kbd>) you'll get the view of the model's right side. And *Viewpoint > Left* (<kbd>Numpad_3</kbd>) is actually the front view. That's confusing.

  - the mesh has a *Mirror* modifier. Set the *Mirror Axis* to `X`
  - choose `Global` for the *[Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html)* (drop-down menu at the top center of the viewport).
  - select the objects (mesh and meta rig), and rotate them by -90° (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) or just enter the number in the sidepanel for *Transformation > Rotation > Z*).
  - the fox and the meta rig should stand now in the direction of the Y-axis as shown in the screenshot.
  - finally, apply the *Rotation* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for both objects.
- the origin (the little orange dot) of the objects is not at the world origin (=at the *bottom*) but in the *center*. This will create the *Root* control of the rig (the circle with the 4 arrows) in the center. This is bad when you want to place the wolf right next to a human because they will be not *on* the ground but *sunken half in* the ground.

  - move everything up so the fox stands on the XY-axis and the origin is at (0,0,0). You can set the origin to (0,0,0) by applying the *Location* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- the left leg of the *meta rig* is not aligned properly and this results in a bad deformation of the leg and pawn. The *right* leg is on the left side of the screen ;-) To fix this just select the *fox's right* leg (meta-rig in *Edit* mode) and use the menu *Armature > Symmetrize* to copy the layout from right to left.

**Now, you can recreate the meta rig**:

- rename your metarig to *metarig.old*
- add a new wolf meta rig
- copy [the script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194425/107598), double-check the names and run it as described in the linked question
- generate the rig. There should be no errors now. Check the N-panel if all bone layers have been created correctly (buttons *Arm.L (FK)* and *Arm.R (FK)*, etc.)

**Set up the rig**

- clear the parent of the meshes (fox amd eyes) and make sure the *Armature* modifier is removed
- select the fox mesh, the eyes, and the generated rig (selected last=parent). Parent them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> with *Automatic Weights*. This will make the meshes children of the armature. In the outliner, they will be listed under the *rig*. This operation also adds an *Armature* modifier to the mesh objects.
- select the *FOX* mesh and check the modifier order. The *Mirror* modifier must be at the top. Next should be the *Armature* modifier, followed by the *Subdivision Surface* modifier at the bottom.
- select the *rig* and test it in *Pose* mode. Don't forget to set the *[Transform Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html)* to *Global* or *Local* and *[Transform Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html)* to *Individual Origins* to rotate the bones properly.