# Miss one hand controller when I use rigify

Tags: rigging

I use rigify to rig my character.
But when I "generate rig" my rig.
I found I miss one controller on the hand.
This controller usually controls the palm.
This is a very important controller.
[image]

Comment: Maybe there is something broken and you need to recreate the meta-rig? [Rigify->Generate Rig doesn't create all rig layers in the properties ui](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/108975/107598)

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. it shows"Python script failed, check the message in the system console
"

Comment: Have created a new meta rig? Have you checked and adjusted the names in the script? Have you copied the correct script? Had you selected the meta rig? What error is displayed in the system console window?