# Copy Bone Positions Between Armatures

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Is there a way or a simple script to copy all bone properties (head position, tail position and roll etc)  from one Armature to another Armature with corresponding names?

Not copying poses from one armature to another but actual bone positions in edit mode.

Comment: If you copy all properties, wouldn't they be the same armature?  You could just specify the armature data used in the top of properties/armature to be the other armature's data.

Comment: There are some differences between the rigs, hence just bones with corresponding names.

Comment: Try this script here => https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194425/107598 You need to tweak it a bit if there are additional bones in the destination rig that do not exist in the source rig. Change line 23 to `if bone_data.get(b.name): b.head, b.tail, b.roll = bone_data[b.name]` to skip the missing bones.