# Same name modelling and texture linking

Tags: python, texturing, uv, vector-mapping

I have folder A and folder B. There are many textures like "Image 1" in folder A, and many terrain models like "Image 2" in folder B. I want to connect the textures of the same name to terrain modeling using "Blender Python".

(Image 1)
[image]
(Image 2)
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"I want to connect the textures of the same name to terrain modeling"*? With Python, you can import the *.obj file with the API operation `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()`, then load the image, create a simple material that uses the image texture, and then assign it to the model. So far, so good. But what should happen then? Import the next one and all into the same current blend file...?

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your reply. I want to load obj from the "image2" folder and load a texture with the same name as obj from the "image1" folder and apply it to obj. For example, after calling "B001DS37115330_00.obj" from "Image 2" to the screen in Blender, call the texture of the same name from "Image 1" and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that imports all *.obj files from a given folder. For each imported model it tries to load a JPG image with the same name from another folder. If found it will create a material from a *template* material and assign it to the imported model. If the model already had a material then the material in the first slot will get replaced. Other material slots are not affected.

**Note:** There must be a *template* material named "*Material for imports*" that has an *Image Texture* node. This material will be duplicated and assigned to the imported model. The image will be replaced with the imported JPG image.

It's recommended to open the *System Console* window (main menu *Window > Toggle System Console*) to check the output of the script for errors. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the console window to abort the script.

```py
import bpy
import os
import glob


def import_obj_file(obj_path):
    
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    # Call the obj import operator and pass the absolute file path
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = obj_path)

    # Get the imported object from context, print the name and its reference
    obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    if not obj is None:
        print(f"Imported {obj.name}, type: {obj.type}")
    else:
        print(f"ERROR: imported object found {obj_path}")
        
    return obj


def load_image(image_folder, image_name):
    
    # look for image. If not found try to load it
    image = bpy.data.images.get(image_name)
    if image is None:
        try:
            # load image
            image_path = f"{image_folder}/{image_name}"
            image = bpy.data.images.load(image_path)
            print(f"Loaded image: {image_path}")
        except:
            print(f"ERROR: Image not found: {image_path}")

    return image    
    
    
def assign_material(obj, image, material_template):
    
    mat_name = obj.name
    
    # look for material, if not found create a new one
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name)
    if mat is None:
        # create new material from template
        template = bpy.data.materials.get(material_template)
        mat = template.copy()
        mat.name = mat_name 
        
    mat.node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image = image

    # assign material to object
    obj.material_slots[0].material = mat
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj_folder = "c:/tmp/objs"          #  <--------- folders with the files to import
    image_folder = "c:/tmp/images" 
    mat_template = "Material for imports"  #  <---- material to be duplicated for all imports
    
    obj_files = glob.glob(f"{obj_folder}/*.obj", recursive = False)
    
    for obj_path in obj_files: 
        imported_obj = import_obj_file(obj_path)
        
        image_basename = os.path.basename(obj_path).split('.')[0]
        image_name = image_basename + ".jpg"       # <--- file extension of images 
                 
        image = load_image(image_folder, image_name)
        
        if not imported_obj is None and not image is None: 
            assign_material(imported_obj, image, mat_template)
        else:
            print("ERROR: cannot assign material, object or image missing")
        
    print(f"{len(obj_files)} files processed.")
```

Check [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194425/107598) on how to run a script in Blender.