# Missing FK and Tweak bones of left leg when generating a rig with rigify

Tags: bones, rigify

[image]When using the rigify addon after setting the complex human metarig and hiting generate rig the generated armature is missing the FK and tweak bones of the left leg and the IK ones are replaced by octaedral bones without any IK function and as you can see there in no option to unhide the left bones , how do I fix this?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of [Rigify->Generate Rig doesn't create all rig layers in the properties ui](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/108975/107598) - The problem is probably an old bug. It still happens in Blender 3.x now and then. If you haven't customized the metarig, you can re-create it easily with script in the linked question/answer. Otherwise, you have to check the Rigify layer settings that define which bone is assigned to which layer. Maybe you can fix it there (see the other answer)... sorry, that's all I know.